# convert logical matrix (TRUE/FALSE) to character matrix (Present/Absent)

Tags: r, matrix, coding-style

I have a matrix (x) that has logical values (TRUE/FALSE). I want to convert these values into characters ('Present'/'Absent') and make them into factors. To illustrate, I have this:

```
 ColA, ColB, ..., ColN

RowA, TRUE, FALSE, ..., TRUE

RowB, FALSE, TRUE, ..., FALSE

...

RowN, TRUE, TRUE, ..., TRUE
```

I want to make this:

```
 ColA, ColB, ..., ColN

RowA, 'Present', Absent', ..., 'Present'

RowB, 'Absent', 'Present', ..., 'Absent'

...

RowN, 'Present', 'Present', ..., 'Present'
```

And I want them to be stored as factors. Does anyone know a simple way to do this? I've been looking and I surprisingly can't find anything that makes sense to me.

Comment: so use a `data.frame` for the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse` should work:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),20,TRUE),nrow=4)
ifelse(mat,'Present','Absent')
```

As far as I can tell, matrices can not have class `factor`, since `factor`s are not `atomic`. See

```
?matrix
?atomic
```

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively,

```
foo<-as.data.frame(matrix('Present',nrow=nrow(yourmat),ncol=ncol(yourmat))
foo[!yourmat]<-'Absent'
```